# Mysql more items after WHERE to select from db

Tags: mysql, select

I have one column named "state". In this column item get number 1,2 or 3 and I would like to select from db just rows with 1 and 2 numbers. I tried to do

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE state = 1 or 2;
```

or

```
$select_state = array(1,2); 
SELECT * FROM db WHERE state = $select_state;
```

But both options are ... I googled for it but doesn't find anything similiar. Can somebody help me with that? Or help me to search where I can find solution?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE state = 1 or state =2;
```

use this statement and try.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

Use where IN(array of id) as below

```
$select_state = array(1,2); 
SELECT * FROM db WHERE state in($select_state);
```